# Is there a way of reading the UDID from with app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, udid

I am developing and app and would like to know if there is any way that I can access the device's UDID from within the app. The reason being the app sends data to an SQL database and I would like to know which device sends it.

Edit: I have just read that Apple have banned this practice. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `+[UIDevice identifierForVendor]` available from iOS 6.0. It provides an unique idenfier for all the apps from the same vendor (provided the user doesn’t uninstall all of them).

Comment: Thanks - Does Apple approve this method?

Comment: Yes, it is documented and recommended by Apple. It’s the alternative they provided to the old `uniqueIdenfier`.